# Nesting If Statements in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am making a cost estimate sheet with Google Sheets, one of the costs is LED strip, each colour of LED strip has a different price. I have made a dropdown to select the colour and used an If statement to try and calculate the price per M x the length of strip needed.

I used the following IF statement in a helper cell:
`=IF(B4="White LED = £1.30 Per M",D4=C4*1.3, IF(B4="Blue LED = £1.80 Per M", D4=C4*1.8, IF(B4="Green LED = £1.80 Per M", D4=C4*1.8, IF(B4="Purple LED = £2 Per M", D4=C4*2, IF(B4="Yellow LED = £1.80 Per M", D4=C4*1.8, IF(B4="Pink LED = £1.80 Per M", D4=C4*1.8, IF(B4="Warm white LED = £1.80 Per M", D4=C4*1.8, IF(B4="Gold LED = £1.80 Per M", D4=C4*1.8, IF(B4="Orange LED = £2.60 per M", D4=C4*2.6, IF(B4="Red LED = £1.80 Per M", D4=C4*1.8))))))))))`

This just returns "FALSE" in the helper cell and does nothing in D4.
Can someone please advise on how to make this work?

[image]

Comment: @rockinfreakshow - I have added an image, please can you take a look. I apologise for not doing this sooner, never used this site before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just remove the `D4=` part(s) in your current formula:*

```js
=IF(B4="White LED = £1.30 Per M",C4*1.3, IF(B4="Blue LED = £1.80 Per M", C4*1.8, IF(B4="Green LED = £1.80 Per M", C4*1.8, IF(B4="Purple LED = £2 Per M", C4*2, IF(B4="Yellow LED = £1.80 Per M", C4*1.8, IF(B4="Pink LED = £1.80 Per M", C4*1.8, IF(B4="Warm white LED = £1.80 Per M", C4*1.8, IF(B4="Gold LED = £1.80 Per M", C4*1.8, IF(B4="Orange LED = £2.60 per M", C4*2.6, IF(B4="Red LED = £1.80 Per M", C4*1.8))))))))))
```

Comment: You may try n' test  this simple alternative instead `=regexextract(B4,"\d+(?:\.\d+)?")*C4`